# Xamarin Forms Shell navigate back with GoToAsync("..") causes exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, xamarin.shell

I have a very simple navigation stack consisting of a root page and then a model page on top of it. My root page is being set as the root by being the first page to be registered with Shell.

```
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // opening view
        Regester<LoginPage>();

        Regester<SignUpPage>();
        ...

    }

    private void Regester<T>()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Regestering with shell : {typeof(T).Name} - {typeof(T)}");
        Items.Add(new ShellContent { Route = typeof(T).Name, ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(T)) });
        Routing.RegisterRoute(typeof(T).Name, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Then I am navigating to the model sign up page using relative routing

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SignUpPage");
```

or I will use absolute routing

```
  Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///LogInPage/SignUpPage");
```

then I will attempt to navigate back in the stack using

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
```

But I get this exception

```
Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported. For now, just navigate to: LoginPage/
```

At the time of exception the CurrentState.Location property is this

```
Location = {///LoginPage/SignUpPage}
```

I don't understand why this is happening. This will also happen if I am further into the stack and doing something like trying to navigate back from a detail page. What do I need to do to be able to use GoToAsync("..") properly?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

Your path `///LogInPage` is invalid . Global routes currently can't be the only page on the navigation stack. Therefore, absolute routing to global routes is unsupported.

**Solution:**

Navigation can also be performed by specifying a valid relative URI as an argument to the GoToAsync method. The routing system will attempt to match the URI to a ShellContent object. Therefore, if all the routes in an application are unique, navigation can be performed by only specifying the unique route name as a relative URI:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SignUpPage");
```